# Anybody has an Idea of compiling the Angular Source Code locally?

Tags: angular

I am trying to compile angular's source code locally. I have tried the instructions given in https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/docs/BAZEL.md

But it seems not working.

After running `bazel build packages/...` command mentioned in doc. I get the Angular Packages compiled but in ES6. I don't know how to get the ES5 version of all the packages. Tried to tweak tsconfig.json, but no luck either.

Answer (score 0):

Run 'ng build' for build. You can add additional '--prod' for production build. In that case you have to configure prod configuration in angular.json. If you want build a project library then use 'ng build project name. Run 'npm  run start' or simply 'ng serve -o'for running the project with default environment.json.

Answer (score 0):

It works for me to run `yarn bazel build packages/...`, be sure your typescript, node, yarn, and bazel all fit the required versions.
Node: v12.22.12, yarn: 1.13.0,bazel/bazelisk@1.11.0

Answer (score -1):

Run `ng build` to build the project. The build artifacts will be stored in the dist/ directory. Use the `--prod` flag for a production build.

Comment: this is the correct answer the question is not correctly worded.